# Replacing the image of the car with something else

Tags: flow-project

Is there a way to swap the default image of the white car used in the flow simulation with another image?

What I tried: I searched the /flow/ directory looking for .jpeg or .png images of a white car. I couldn't find any. Is this being generated via pure code?

Comment: Hi, we've switched to slack for questions of this sort, could you post it there? https://join.slack.com/t/flow-users/shared_invite/enQtODQ0NDYxMTQyNDY2LTY1ZDVjZTljM2U0ODIxNTY5NTQ2MmUxMzYzNzc5NzU4ZTlmNGI2ZjFmNGU4YjVhNzE3NjcwZTBjNzIxYTg5ZmY

Comment: Sure can! Thank you for the invitation.